# Array Foreach vs Map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

Trying passing an array but unable to display the options list. I'd appreciate your help. Thank you.

```
const options_A = [
        { label: "AA", value: "AA" },
        { label: "BB", value: "BB" },
        { label: "CC", value: "CC" },
  ]
```

```
    
    return (
            {/* <option value="d">dfdf</option> */}
                { 
                    options.forEach(element => {
                        <option value={element.value}>{element.label}</option>
                    })
                }
            </select>
            
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `map` instead of `forEach`.

```
options.map(element => ( 
      <option value={element.value}>{element.label}</option>
 ))
```

Comment: I already tried using map. Doesn't work.

Comment: make sure to remove the curly brackets

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-brook-0vn6jb?file=/src/Floating.tsx